# GSON: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: java, json

I am getting a GSON error trying to unmarshal JSON into an object.  The error (**Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 3 column 22**) is pointing to line 3 of the input below.

Have I not mapped the JSON correctly with respect to the Bean?

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

public class BusinessPartnerCreate {
    protected JAXBElement<String> partnerType;
    protected Person person;
    protected Company company;
    protected String email;
    protected String phone;
    protected AddressData addressData;
    protected AddressClean addressClean;
    protected String city;
    protected String state;
    protected String zipCode;
    protected JAXBElement<String> externalId;
}
```

And my input JSON looks is this:

```
{
    "business-partner-create": {
        "partner-type": "1",
        "person": {
            "firstName": "Dirk",
            "lastName": "Wintermill",
            "title": ""
        },
        "email": "kirk@yahoo.com",
        "phone": "219-385-2946",
        "addressClean": {
            "house-number": "10218",
            "street-name": "Park",
            "street-abbr": "Rd"
        },
        "city": "Somerset",
        "state": "NJ",
        "zip-code": "01955"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you've not mapped it correctly as your json object isn't a `BusinessPartnerCreate`, it contains a `BusinessPartnerCreate`.

You can  create a class just to encapsulate your `BusinessPartnerCreate` but it would be cleaner to deserialize the container as a `jsonObject` using

```
 JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
 JsonObject obj = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
```

and then parse the interesting content using

```
BusinessPartnerCreate bpc = gson.fromJson(obj.get("business-partner-create"), BusinessPartnerCreate.class);
```

And I suggest you add an annotation to ensure proper mapping of the `partnerType` field :

```
   @SerializedName "partner-type"
   protected JAXBElement<String> partnerType;
```

(and similar for zip-code)